# A mesh "jumps" forward after parenting to an armature

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

When I parent mesh to an armature (automatic weights), the mesh "jumps" forward a bit. If I select armature and switch to edit mode it "jumps" backward a bit.

Why is it happening and how can I fix it?
I already applied location, rotation, and scale to the mesh and armature, but it didn't help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The rest pose (pose mode) does not correspond to the default (edit) bones position. So you should either: in pose mode apply pose as rest pose (ctrl+A then choose the corresponding) => consequence, bones in edit mode will be at the pose position. Or: still in pose mode, use the pose menu and clear transform/all => consequence the pose will come back to the edit position of the bones. In both cases, you'll probably need to parent again. The idea behind all that is to have a "rest pose" where bones both in pose and edit modes are at the same position (which is the best practice, afaik)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of an armature, edited in pose mode and, after this edit, made parent to the mesh (a cube):

[image]

This involves a 'shift' between pose and edit mode.

You could say 'there is no stable position for the mesh'.

To correct that, two possibilities: move the pose back to the edit position, or move the edit position to the pose.

- Move the pose back to the edit position

To do that, simply use the pose menu, go to 'clear transform' and select 'all'. Doing this the pose will come back to the edit position:

[image]

- Move the edit position to the pose

This time, we use the pose menu, go to pose then 'apply' (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) and choose 'pose as rest pose'. Doing that, the edit position will be the pose position.

[image]

In both approach, the result is bones positions are the same in edit mode and pose mode (which is the best practice to define a 'stable' or 'reference' rest pose).

Depending on your need, you may have to parent mesh to armature again after that.

Additional indications: to avoid all that, adjust the bones in edit mode, not in pose mode. Also, if you scale the armature to the mesh, don't forget to apply this scale (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) before parenting to the mesh.

Comment: But if the armature already animated it works only until I move to the next frame in the timeline and then the effect gone. Is there also a way to fix the problem for an animated armature?